# Docker Postgres Image not accessible

Tags: postgresql, docker

So, I pulled the postgres image down from docker. I followed a tutorial which explained what's going with the command below and the the whole docker pull. I can log in to the instance fine. But when I restart my computer or shutdown docker I end up goign through similar setup steps and am not able to access the postgres instance anymore. Can someone explain what's going on here:

1. Run this command
   `docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -d postgres -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data  postgres`
2. log in via PG admin.

Nothing, instance not available.

So, I feel like I am missing a step at one point I had executed a command like this: 
`docker exec -it c5b8bdd0820b35a01ea153a44e82458a6285cf484b701b2b2d6d4210266fb4f8 bash`

which gave me acess to the shell for the image, after doing that I was able then to use PGAdmin, however, I feel like that may have been coincidence? As this does not work currently.

So, what am I doing wrong? What's an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The --rm causes Docker to automatically remove the container when it exits. Remove it. 
You can also add `--restart always` and your container will be up after restart.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! I thought the -rm just removed it after I stopped the container